# Getting the output value from another function in c

Tags: c

```
int assign(int *m){
    //static int n = 9;
    // m = &n;    // will assign the value to the variable a = 9
    *m = 10;
    // int n =8;
    // m = &n;   //  will fail as the scope of the variable is within the function
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int a ;
    assign(&a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

ans: a= 10   Is there any other way to get the output in a (without passing the address and using the pointer and parameter to the function)

Comment: can you just do `int assign() {return 10;}` and in main `a = assign();` to assign the value to a.

Comment: Who is "he" and why is he outputting values?

Comment: Yes, if you do not need the return value for other purposes then...use it for what it is: a return value! :) Otherwise no, you do not have any other option in C (you may consider to return a struct instead of a primitive type but it's a bad idea for performances).

Comment: @wes:sorry that is the.@twain: I will return true or false to check the return type and i dont want to pass the data while returning.

Comment: Declare a global variable, change the value of global in `assign` & assign `a` the value of global after the call to `assign`... Voila!! :P

Comment: Don't do what another.anon.coward said...it is terrible practice to use global variables in unnecessary situations like this.  If you're using the return value for something else, then this is the correct way to return another value.

Comment: @AaronDufour: Most certainly not!! It is *a* method and ofc, not a recommended one

Answer (score 2):

Each function in C allows you to return a single value.

```
int assign(......)
 ^
 |
output type
```

You do so by using the `return` keyword. A function that returns something, is like any other expression with the same type.

For example, if you have:

```
int assign(void)
{
    return 10;
}
```

all of the following are valid:

```
int a = assign();
int b = (assign()*20)-assign()/assign();
```

The reason why you might need to use pointers in arguments is to have more than a single output.

For example, take a function that goes over an array and returns the minimum and maximum:

```
void minmax(int *array, int size, int *minimum, int *maximum)
{
    int i;
    int min_overall = INT_MAX;
    int max_overall = INT_MIN;
    /* error checking of course, to make sure parameters are not NULL */
    /* Fairly standard for: */
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] < min_overall)
            min_overall = array[i];
        if (array[i] > max_overall)
            max_overall = array[i];
    }
    /* Notice that you change where the pointers point to */
    /* not the pointers themselves: */
    *minimum = min_overall;
    *maximum = max_overall;
}
```

and in your `main`, you can use it like this:

```
int arr[100];
int mini, maxi;
/* initialize array */
minmax(arr, 100, &mini, &maxi);
```

**Edit**: Since you asked if there is any other way to do it, here is an example (although I absolutely do NOT recommend it for a usage like yours):

```
struct assign_ret
{
    int return_value;
    int assigned_value;
};

struct assign_ret assign(void)
{
    assign_ret ret;
    ret.assigned_value = 10;
    ret.return_value = 0;
    return ret;
}
```

and in `main`:

```
struct assign_ret result = assign();
if (result.return_value != 0)
    handle_error();
a = result.assigned_value;
```

The reason why I don't recommend this, is that `struct` is used to place data that are relevant together. Function error return value and its data output are not relevant.